# How to cancel flexible in-app update while downloading?

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-update, google-play-core

I couldn't find it in the documentation of `AppUpdateManager`, but I hope it's possible. The question is how to enable user to cancel the download of the update?

In particular when the `requestUpdateFlow()` returns `AppUpdateResult.InProgress`.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of `flexible` there is no direct way to cancel the update, user have to force stop the app or turn off the internet, so in this case, you will get the result `RESULT_CANCELED` on `onActivityResult`.

Comment: Actually, when you turn off the internet, you won't get result `RESULT_CANCELED`. Instead the `InstallState` should change.